# std::valarray and type of iterators

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator

Since C++11 `std::valarray` has iterators, provided through the `std::begin()` and `std::end()` interfaces. But what is the type of those iterators (so that I can declare them properly)?

The following does not compile with a `no template named 'iterator' in 'valarray<_Tp>'` error:

```
template <typename T>
class A {
private:
  std::valarray<T> ar;
  std::valarray<T>::iterator iter;
public:
  A() : ar{}, iter{std::begin(ar)} {}
};
```

`decltype` shows the type of the iterator to be that of a pointer to a ``valarray` element. Indeed, the following does compile and seems to work fine:

```
template <typename T>
class A {
private:
  std::valarray<T> ar;
  T* iter;
public:
  A() : ar{}, iter{std::begin(ar)} {}
};
```

What am I missing? Isn't there a proper iterator type to use for the declare in the class?

Comment: You could cheat: `decltype(std::begin(ar)) iter;`

Comment: A pointer is a proper iterator type.

Comment: @super But `decltype(std::begin(ar))` isn't necessarily a pointer type.

Comment: @super If that is a guarantee `begin( valarray<T>& v );` should be specified as returning `T*` or `const T*` - but it's not. It's _unspecified_.

Comment: @TedLyngmo How do you go from *a pointer is a valid iterator type* to *a iterator must be a pointer*... ? AFAIK a pointer meets all the requirements of a random access iterator. Is that wrong?

Comment: @eerorika Indeed. I just pointed out that i *can* be a pointer.

Comment: @super I'm not sure I understand your question. The standard does not say that it has to be a `T*` (or `const T*`) so even if a pointer would certainly be fine, the standard does not require it to be a pointer. Perhaps I read too much into your first comment _"A pointer is a proper iterator type"_, because a pointer is not guaranteed to be a proper iterator type for `valarray`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo A pointer is a proper iterator type. That was the whole comment. There was nothing more hidden in there.

Comment: @super I think I understand now. You meant that to address only the _"Isn't there a proper iterator type"_ part of OP:s last sentence, leaving _"to use for the declare in the class?"_ out?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes. From OPs wording it seems unclear to me if OP is aware that a pointer could be the iterator type that `valarray` uses.

Comment: @super I see how it could be interpreted that way even though I didn't. Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But what is the type of those iterators

The type is unspecified.

> (so that I can declare them properly)?

You can use decltype:

```
using It = decltype(std::begin(ar));
It iter;
```

Or, in cases where that's possible (not member variables), you should prefer type deduction:

```
auto iter = std::begin(ar);
```